# Does systemctl enable also restart the service

Tags: systemd

The [`systemctl enable`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#enable%20UNIT%E2%80%A6) command does a `daemon-reload`. If the service is already running, does that also result in a restart of the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

`daemon-reload` basically re-reads the configuration from all the unit files.  But it does not perform the `restart` (or even `reload`) actions on any unit.

For example, if you change the `ExecStart=` line for a service, it will not change the currently running process.  The new `ExecStart=` command will be used if you restart the service.